# How to get JSON data for Learnpress courses?

Tags: android, json, wordpress, android-volley, wordpress-rest-api

I have a wordpress website built with LearnPress. I want to create an android app for the website. So, I'll be needing the JSON data for courses and stuff related to user. Where can I get that data?

I am able to find the JSON data for users using the JSON API USER plugin. But I can only authenticate with it. How can I get other details such as courses, etc of the user in JSON form?

Please help!

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Please check the updated question

Comment: Unfortunately still there is no official REST API available from Learnpress developers team, but someone here has tried to develop it by himself. You may find it helpful, have a look at it ->> https://github.com/LearnPress/learnpress/pull/243